# Creating js tabs with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I need some help regarding tabs.

We are building a intranet portal for our clients, where they will be able to create business cards and more. But we've come to a halt because of problems with tabs.

We need to have a approx 1-4 steps process in tabs. 1 step is to select a business card template. When the template is chosen the next step would be to fill it out.

However each template has different kinds of input fields making the height of the step 2 tab variable.

We've tried using the tabs from Jquery UI, but only the first step is working, since the next step on some templates will be cut off, because of the height.

What is the best way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can't u also write some code like `height()` to fix the jquery ui thing? I think jquery ui is the best choice.

Comment: The problem is that we don't know the height of tab 2 before the step in tab 1 has been completed. But the tabs have already been loaded so we can't "reload" them and then give it the height. At least not that we have been able to find.

Comment: Can't you dynamically load the content into the tab's with ajax, I have my search results coming back into 4 different tabs with different heights and it's all good. Maybe you have a float issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've used JQuery tabs a lot, and never seen this problem.  AFAIK, there is nothing about the tabs themselves that restricts the content that can be put inside them.  I would try removing all the logic, html, additional js etc from your tabs, and making the content simple (a series of divs with a fixed height for example).  I think you will see that the tabs simply open up to the full height of their contents.  Then start adding your code back in until you find whatever it is that restricts the height of your tabs.  BTW, I don't think it makes any difference whether they tabs are statically created or loaded via ajax either ...

Comment: We will try and do it one thing at a time and see if we can get it to work :)